# Why does the serial number on Google's certificate as returned by Java's SSL differ from that returned from Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: java, firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using the following code in Java to print out various properties of Google's certificate.

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;

import javax.net.*;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/*
 * Start an connection with google.com and submit to Google to figure out how to get the certificate.
 * Should not pull from artificial context.
 */
public class MWE{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
        SocketFactory clientSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        String remoteHost = "google.com";
        int remotePort = 443;
        SSLSocket socket = null;
        try {
            //Lookup the "common name" field of the certificate from the remote server:
            socket = (SSLSocket) clientSocketFactory.createSocket(remoteHost, remotePort);
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            socket.startHandshake();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        X509Certificate[] c = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificateChain();
        X509Certificate serverCertificate = c[0]; //can I control which instance of this is used?
        Principal serverDN = serverCertificate.getSubjectDN();
        BigInteger serverSerialNumber = serverCertificate.getSerialNumber();

        System.out.println(serverCertificate.getClass());
        System.out.println(serverDN);
        System.out.println(serverSerialNumber.toString(16));
        System.out.println(serverCertificate.getSigAlgName());

        System.out.println(serverCertificate.getNotBefore());
        System.out.println(serverCertificate.getNotAfter());
    }
}
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
CN=*.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
1484d9a3000000007d35
SHA1withRSA
Wed Feb 20 05:34:43 PST 2013
Fri Jun 07 12:43:27 PDT 2013
```

However, when I  view the certificate from Firefox or Chrome, everything matches except the serial number.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Firefox certificate info shows the certificate for [`www.google.com`](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.google.com), while your Java code displays the certificate for [`google.com`](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=google.com).

Those two sites have different certificates, and therefore different serials.